# How can i make an intelligent search with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some campaings running in my site and each campaign has many media images, the user recieves this image when in site and once seen the stage is saved (so we know which images the user saw).

I need:
 when user comes to my site show him a media that he didnt saw before (it may be not possible sometimes so ill have to repeat) and also i need to add some percetage or value to the campaigns to give more weight and specify which are more important to bring it more times than the others.

So how can i make that query or how many queries do i need?

Edit:

I tried to get like 5 randoms and select from them the one with best perc. the thing is that most of the time it gets the same and some campaigns are never shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might use 2 queries, first one to detect the best campaing taking x number random and check the best perc. of them

Then search a media of this campaign that user didnt saw, if no results you can get a random of them